# Core dump not in sync with gdb stack trace

Tags: c++, gdb, crash-dumps, hp-ux

I have a program which crashes due to a segmentation fault. The core file is produced.

running the core in gdb gives me the following:

> HP gdb 6.1 for HP Itanium (32 or 64 bit) and target HP-UX 11iv2 and 11iv3.
>
> Core was generated by `gcpf1fwcApp'.
> Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted.

I used the command

> thread apply all bt

When I check the stack trace I get error in the main thread which is in waiting state.

However when I run the same program in GDB I get a completely different error in stack trace. Which seems more correct than the core dump.

The program has 31 threads.

Why do I get this kind of difference?

Comment: Is your program multi-threaded? Please provide what commands you have used in GDB. With precisely what where you comparing the GDB output? Where you analyzing core on the same machine where it was produced?

Comment: Yes the program is multi-threaded. It has 31 threads.
I was comparing the back trace produced by the core file with the one from running the program inside gdb.
The only command I used was "thread apply all bt".
I used gdb like so: gdb -c <core> <program>.
Yes its on the same machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible that you are simply looking at the wrong thread.

Try `thread apply all where`, and see if one of the threads is in fact `abort()`ing.

When debugging a live process, GDB will stop when a thread receives `SIGABRT`, and so will likely show you the relevant thread.

When debugging a core (post-mortem), GDB doesn't know which thread is relevant, and so shows them to you in whichever order the OS saved them into the core. Linux kernels save the thread which caused the process to die first, so GDB on Linux shows relevant thread from core. I am guessing that HP-UX does not do that, and so GDB shows you a "random" thread instead.

Comment: Yes I used thread apply all bt. First it does not show me the relevant thread. Second the relevant thread has nothing showing that it has crashed. It just shows it in thread waiting state. No clues whatsoever that the actual thread has in fact crashed.